# Möbius transformations on $D$ such that $f(D)=D$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find all Möbius transformations on unit disk such that $f(D)=D$, please help!

Comment: what did you try so far? what properties of möbius transforms do you know. Which did you use?

Comment: Do you know how to find all the Moebius transformations that preserve the reals? (x-axis)

Comment: I thought --> 1.any mobius transformation circle is mapped to a circle(Check this)
2. by 1 I am $ |f(z)|=1 $ while $ |z|=1$

3.also notice the fact that |f(0)|<1

4. say $f(z)= (az+b)/(cz+d).$ now how to find a,b,c,d using above info and basic properties of mobius transformation?

Comment: @DennisGulko Not really dear sir

Answer (score 4):

Mapping from $D$ to $D$ is onto, so exist $z_0 \in D$ such that $B(z_0)=0$. Using correspondence principle of border (I don't know English version of this theorem) we find that $B(T)=T$, where $T=\{\omega \in \mathbb{C}: |\omega|=1\}$, and $B(z_0^*)=\infty$ (which is same as $B\left(\dfrac{1}{\overline{z_0}}\right)$, where $z_0^*$ is inverse point of $z_0$ with respect to the circle $T$).

Now, $$\omega=B(z)=K \dfrac{z-z_0}{z-\frac{1}{\overline{z_0}}}=-\overline{z_0}K\dfrac{z-z_0}{1-\overline{z_0}z}=K_1\dfrac{z-z_0}{1-\overline{z_0}z},\qquad K_1=-\overline{z_0}K.$$

Using that $|B(e^{it})|=1, \, t \in [0,2\pi)$ we find 
$$1=|B(e^{it})|=|K_1|\frac{|e^{it}-z_0|}{|1-\overline{z_0}e^{it}|}=\frac{|K_1|}{|e^{it}|}\frac{|e^{it}-z_0|}{|e^{-it}-\overline{z_0}|}=|K_1|,$$
so $K_1=e^{i\alpha}$ for some $\alpha \in [0, 2\pi)$.
So, $$\omega=B(z)=e^{i\alpha} \frac{z-z_0}{1-\overline{z_0}z},\, \alpha \in [0,2\pi),\, |z_0|<1$$

Comment: How can you conclude that $z_0^\star$ is the same as $\frac{1}{\bar{z_0}}$?

Comment: @DimitrisDallas $z_0^*=\dfrac{1}{\overline{z_0}}$ because $z_0^*$ is inverse point of $z_0$ with respect to unit circle $T$. You can show that if we have circle $k=k(z_0,r), r>0$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}-\{z_0\}$ arbitrary point, then inverse point of $z$ is $z^*=\frac{r^2}{\overline{z-z_0}}$. In our example, $z_0 = z$, so $z_0^*=\frac{1^2}{\overline{z_0-0}}=\frac{1}{\overline{z_0}}$

Comment: I mean that I cannot understand why $B(z_0)=0$ implies $B\left(\dfrac{1}{\overline{z_0}}\right)=\infty$

Comment: @DimitrisDallas Ahh, ok. Well, one property of Möbius transformation is that inverse point maps to inverse point. In our case, $z_0^*$ is inverse point of $z_0$ and $\infty$ is inverse point of  $\,0$, so if $B(z_0)=0$ then $B(z_0^*)=0^*=\infty$. I hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

**Outline of solution:**
1) First, show that $\varphi$ is a Moebius transformation such that $\varphi(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $\varphi(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$. You can do this by looking at $\varphi(0),\varphi(\infty)$ and $\varphi(1)$.
2) Take any Moebius transformation $\psi(z)$ such that $\psi(D)=\mathbb{R}$. (e.g. $\psi(z)=\frac{iz+1}{z+i}$). Show that a Moebius transformation $f(z)$ satisfies $f(D)=D$ if and only if $\varphi=\psi\circ f\circ\psi^{-1}$ satisfies $\varphi(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$.
3) Use the first two steps and some algebraic manipulations to show that $f(z)=\frac{w_1z+w_2}{\overline{w_2}z+\overline{w_1}}$ for some $w_1,w_2\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|w_1|\neq|w_2|$.