# How to show that $\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}$ maps $\mathbb{T}$ into $\mathbb{T}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show that $\dfrac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}$ maps $\mathbb{T}$ into $\mathbb{T}$, where $\mathbb{T}=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|=1\}$? How it is possible that just three points is enough to show that?

Comment: Did you mean $\dfrac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$?

Comment: You should mention what is $\mathbb{T} $.

Comment: $\,\Bbb T\,$ can be lots of things, even if we focus on linear fractional transformations, complex analysis or whatever. To expect all know what you mean is a long shot.

Comment: If you don't like "three point method" then show that  $\left|\dfrac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}\right|=1$ for $|z|=1$.

Comment: My guess is that (1) Daniel Fischer was right: $a*$ should be $a^\ast$ or $\overline a$, the complex conjugate, and (2) $\mathbb T$ is the unit circle $\{z\in\mathbb C : |z|=1\}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I meant $a^*=\bar{a}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Lemma.* If $L$ is bilinear maps for which one are points $0$, $\infty$ and $1$ fixed, then $L$ is identic map.

*Proof.* From $L(\infty)=\infty$ we conclude that $L$ is entire linear function, $$L(z)=Az+B.$$ But, from $L(0)=0$ we get $B=0$, and from $L(1)=1$ that $A=1$. So, $L(z)=z$. $\blacksquare$

*Theorem.* For every three different points $z_1,z_2,z_3 \in \mathbb{C}$ and three different points $w_1,w_2,w_3$ there exist unique bilinear map $L$ such that $L(z_k)=w_k,\, k=1,2,3.$

*Proof.* Construct bilinear mapping $L_1$ and $L_2$ which maps $z_1,z_2,z_3$ and $w_1,w_2,w_3$, respectively, in points $0,\infty$ and $1$.

$$L_1(z)=\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2} \cdot \frac{z_3-z_2}{z_3-z_1}, \quad L_2(w)=\frac{w-w_1}{w-w_2}\cdot \frac{w_3-w_2}{w_3-w_1}.$$

Our map is $L=L_2^{-1} \circ L_1$, that is $w=L_2^{-1} \circ L_1(z).$

So, $L_2(w)=L_1(z)$, that is $$\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2} \cdot \frac{z_3-z_2}{z_3-z_1}=\frac{w-w_1}{w-w_2}\cdot \frac{w_3-w_2}{w_3-w_1}.$$

Let prove unique of this maps. Let $A$ be bilinear map such that $A(z_k)=w_k \, (k=1,2,3)$. As points $0,\infty$ and $1$ are fixed points of bilinear mapping $B=L_2 \circ A \circ L_1^{-1}$, then Lemma is giving us that $B=E,$ where $E$ is identic map. From that, using laws of group, we get $A=L_2^{-1} \circ L_1$, that is $A=L$. $\blacksquare$

For first question see [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325423/how-to-show-that-phi-az-fracz-a1-baraz-is-mapping-phi-az-mathb?rq=1)

Comment: Could you please write how is it that for example $\phi_a(i) \rightarrow w \in \mathbb{D}$ $w=?$. What is this $w$ if $a\in \mathbb{D}$? Does it belong to $\mathbb{D}, \forall a\in \mathbb{D}$?