# Proving that $\phi_a(z) = (z-a)/(1-\overline{a}z)$ maps $B(0,1)$ onto itself.

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

I want to prove that if $\phi_a: B(0,1) \to \Bbb C$ is given by $\phi_a(z) = (z-a)/(1-\overline{a}z)$ with $|a| < 1$, then $|\phi_a(z)| < 1$.

Resist the itch on your finger urging you to close the question: I already took a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188483/suppose-a1-show-that-fracz-a1-overlineaz-is-a-mobius-transformat) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325423/how-to-show-that-phi-az-fracz-a1-baraz-is-mapping-phi-az-mathb).

I'm supposed to prove things in the most elementary way possible (not by choice, sadly). Meaning: no Möbius transformations (I haven't studied them yet, anyway), no exponential maps, etc.

My attempt so far: $$ \begin{align} |\phi_a(z)| &< 1  \iff  \left| \frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}\right| <1 \iff \\ \iff |z-a| &< |1-\overline{a}z|   \iff |z-a|^2 < |1-\overline{a}z|^2 \iff \\ \iff |z|^2-&2\,{\rm Re}(\overline{a}z)+|a|^2 < 1  -2\,{\rm Re}(\overline{a}z)+|\overline{a}z|^2 \iff \\ \iff &|z|^2 + |a|^2 < 1 + |a|^2|z|^2\end{align}$$

I'm stuck here. If $|a|^2 < |a|^2|z|^2$, then I could go back on these implications, but this is false (would give $|z|^2 > 1$).

Is there a way to save this, or there is another (elementary) approach? Thanks!

Comment: How do you get that $Re(\bar{\alpha} z)=Re(\alpha z)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: rearrange $|z|^2 + |a|^2 < 1 + |a|^2 |z|^2$ by putting the terms with $|z|^2$ on one side and the others on the other side, and divide...

Comment: Oh, silly me! Ok, I did it. Thanks. (gotta wait 4 min)