# Möbius transformation maps inverse points to inverse points?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

Say $f$ is a Möbius transformation that maps the unit disk to the unit disk. The solution in this page, and in many other pages [Möbius transformations on $D$ such that $f(D)=D$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318060/m%c3%b6bius-transformations-on-d-such-that-fd-d) says

"Let $z_0$ be the point s.t. $f(z_0)=0$. Then $f(1/\overline{z_0})=\infty$."

In a comment on the post, it says "one property of Möbius transformation is that inverse point maps to inverse point." How can this property be true? It is definitely wrong for a general Möbius transformation s.t. $z/(z-1)$. So I think it is only true in this problem. But why is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inversion in this context means “inversion at a circle”. In the (extended) complex plane, inversion (or reflection) can be defined as follows:

> Let $C$ be a circle (or line) in $\Bbb {\hat C}$, $z \in \Bbb {\hat C}$, and $T$ a Möbius transformation which maps $C$ onto $\Bbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$. Then 
>   $$
>  w = T^{-1}(\overline {T(z)})
> $$
>   is the inverse point (or reflection point) of $z$ with respect to $C$.

It can be shown that this definition is independent of the choice of $T$ (because any Möbius transformation $S$ mapping the real axis onto itself satisfies $S(\bar z) = \overline {S(z)}$).

For lines, this definition coincides with the usual definition of reflection at a line. For circles, it coincides with [“circle inversion”](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inversion.html).

It also follows from the definition that this relation is preserved under Möbius transformations:

> Let $C$ be a circle or line, and $T$ a Möbius transformation. If $w$ is the inverse point of $z$ with respect to $C$ then $T(w)$ is the inverse point of $T(z)$ with respect to $T(C)$.

In the case $T(C) = C$ we conclude that

> Let $C$ be a circle or line, and $T$ a Möbius transformation which maps $C$ onto itself. If $z$, $w$ are inverse points with respect to $C$ then $T(z)$, $T(w)$ are also inverse points with respect to $C$.

and that is the precise meaning of *“.... one property of  Möbius transformation is that inverse point maps to inverse point.”*

In the case of the *unit circle* we can choose $T(z) = i\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ as the mapping onto the real line, and a straight-forward calculation show that

> $1/\overline z$ is the inverse point of $z$ with respect to the unit circle.

In particular, $z=\infty$ is the inverse point of $z=0$. If $f$ is a Möbiustransformation preserving the unit disk and $f(z_0) = 0$ then it follows from the above invariance that $f(1/\overline{z_0}) = \infty$.